# Facebook API to upload photos to current logged in user's album using Javascript

Tags: facebook

How can we upload photos to current logged in user's album. I mean the user have given access to the app to upload photos and stream.

All stuff must have to be done using javascript. 
Any type of help is appreciated.

Comment: If the image is already available on a webserver and publicly available via HTTP, then it’s easy using the parameter `url` instead of `source`. But when images that are only available client-side should be uploaded, things get way more complicated – you would have to use the HTML5 file API to read the image file contents, and then send it to the server in the same way a POST form in HTML would be send.

Comment: Gunah Gaar : Did you find something helpfull to complete this? @CBroe : How to get it done? I'm trying to implement the same, But struck with the ajax request. Is there any format to construct the ajax request? How to include the file name in the post request.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be useful. By doing photo upload to FB only with the help of javascript you can use the following method. Required thing here are imageData(which is base64 format of image) and the mime type.

```
try{
        blob = dataURItoBlob(imageData,mimeType);
}catch(e){console.log(e);}
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("access_token",accessToken);
fd.append("source", blob);fd.append("message","Kiss");
try{
   $.ajax({
        url:"https://graph.facebook.com/" + <<userID received on getting user details>> + "/photos?access_token=" + <<user accessToken>>,
        type:"POST"
        data:fd,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success " + data);
        },
        error:function(shr,status,data){
            console.log("error " + data + " Status " + shr.status);
        },
        complete:function(){
            console.log("Ajax Complete");
        }
    });

}catch(e){console.log(e);}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI,mime) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs

    var byteString = window.atob(dataURI);

    // separate out the mime component


    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    //var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
    var blob = new Blob([ia], { type: mime });

    return blob;
}
```